# Has anyone encountered this error working with webbot

Tags: python, python-3.x

I checked the files within the package and the .exe that its looking for is there and the path is correct from what i see but it wont import webbot for some reason.

heres the code:

```
from webbot import Browser 
web = Browser()
web.go_to('google.com') 
web.type('hello its me')
web.press(web.Key.ENTER)
web.go_back()
web.click('Sign in')
web.type('mymail@gmail.com' , into='Email')
web.click('NEXT' , tag='span')
web.type('mypassword' , into='Password' , id='passwordFieldId')
web.click('NEXT' , tag='span')
```

heres the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "1.py", line 2, in <module>
    web = Browser('C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\webbot\drivers\chrome_windows')
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\webbot\webbot.py", line 50, in __init__
    os.chmod(driverpath , 0o755 )
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified: 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Python37-32\\lib\\site-packages\\webbot\\drivers\\chrome_windows'
```

Comment: i could answer "nope". but it is probably more constructive to advice you to provide more details about the environment and the process leading to this error :) a code example allowing to potentially reproduce the error for example

Comment: Nothing crazy i was testing. i'll add the code in now. The errors is on line 2

Comment: running it with Python 3.6 in a Linux environment seems OK: browser opens and try to log to Google account. I won't be able to help